# How to access relation entity values from a list

Tags: .net, entity-framework, generics, reflection, reflection.emit

Work on EF4 Vs2010 C#. Have one list it’s type is **List**.want to retrieve it’s relational entity list information.In my bellow picture **_entity** is my base list and this list **relational** entity name is **PurQuotationDetails** . I want to access this relation entity properties with values.

I use bellow syntax to access relational entity.

```
foreach (PurQuotationMaster itemMaster in _entity)
{
    foreach (var itemDetail in item.PurQuotationDetails)
    {

    }
}
```

Can not use above syntax reason is ,Want to write a generic  syntax where I just know the parent entity type ,don’t know the **relational** entity type. I use bellow syntax to identify  relational entity **but fail** to access  it’s properties and values.Help me to retrieve it’s values.

```
foreach (PurQuotationMaster item in _entity)
{
    foreach (MemberInfo mi in item.GetType().GetMembers().Where((MemberInfo member) => member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property))
    {
        if (mi.ToString().Contains("EntityCollection`1"))
        {
            var prop = item.GetType().GetProperty(mi.Name);
        }
    }               
}
```

[image]

May be I need to use **RestrictedMemberAccess (RMA)** to access non public members. The concept is a bit tricky to understand .Need help to use **RMA**  syntax on my above situation.

If have any query please ask .Any type of suggestion will be appreciated,Help me to write syntax to retrieve my  desired output.Thanks in advanced.